# Can Doomfist punch Junkrat's RIP-Tire?

Tags: overwatch

Today I was watching a game of Overwatch where someone tried using Doomfist's Rocket Punch to knock Junkrat's RIP-Tire off a cliff.

Doomfist ended up missing and falling off the cliff, but the idea of punching a RIP-Tire off a cliff still lingers in the back of my head.

- Can Doomfist hit Junkrat's RIP-Tire with Rocket Punch?
- Will the RIP-Tire be knocked backwards?
- Does the same apply for Doomfist's Rising Uppercut?

Comment: if hit, the tire should be killed immediately

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: Killfeed]

Yes, Doomfist can punch and damage a RIP-tire. However, the tire is immune to knockback, so it won't be hit back and take damage from impacting into a wall.

Comment: Does Doomfist stop moving when he collides with the tire?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Most likely.

Comment: Most likely, or no?

Comment: @Kaizerwolf I said most likely.